# Get it's "parent" in side System.Timers.Timer

Tags: c#, timer

Well, the title is confusing because I don't know how to express it well, feel free to correct it.

I have a class TaskTimer to access and modify some of it's property, but I don't know how to get it's parent in the elapsed timer event. I do this because whenever i stop a System.Timers.Timer it is still running for the last time. By doing this it will help preventing the timer from misfiring.

```
    public List<TaskTimer> _taskTimers; 
    public void CreateTask(int _taskID, int _invterval)
    {
        TaskTimer taskTimer = new TaskTimer();
        taskTimer.taskID = _taskID;
        taskTimer.Interval = _invterval;
        taskTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTweakTimedEvent_autoTask);
        _taskTimers.Add(taskTimer);
    }
    public class TaskTimer : System.Timers.Timer
    {
        private int taskID { get ; set ;}
    }
```

Here is a sample of Eslapsed timer event and what i want to do:

```
    string currentTaskID = "something";
    private void OnTweakTimedEvent_autoTask(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentTask == {tell this event to get it's taskID)
        {
            //to do here
        }
    }
```

I know this question sounds silly, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Maybe `var parent = sender as TaskTimer` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have *inherited* directly from `Timer`

```
public class TaskTimer : System.Timers.Timer
```

Then the `sender` parameter should be the `TaskTimer`. The exception to this is, if you call this method directly and supply *null* or something else

```
private void OnTweakTimedEvent_autoTask(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
   // safety first
   if(sender is not TaskTimer parent)
      throw new InvalidOperationException("Hmm, Error you must have");
  
   Console.WriteLine(parent.TaskID); 
}
```

Comment: lol i dont know there is literally a thing called parent xD thank you!

Comment: @takatto `parent` is just a variable, assigned in the pattern matching expression in the `if`

Comment: Ah my mistake, i mean "sender as".